# ListView isn't resizing when keyboard is shown

Tags: java, android, listview, keyboard, resize

I have an Activity which shows a ListView. The items in the ListView have EditText fields in them, so when they tap a textfield the virtual keyboard slides into view. It is covering the ListView so you can't see the items behind the keyboard.

I've configured the Manifest for that Activity to adjustResize:

```
<activity android:name=".StatisticalActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                  >
```

.. but it isn't resizing when the keyboard is shown.

This the layout for my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40sp" android:paddingLeft="4dp" android:background="@drawable/toolbar_gradient" android:paddingRight="6dp">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/tableView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#333"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kenny Wyland: "The items in the ListView have EditText fields in them" -- I would avoid this.

Comment: That's just not feasible in this situation and in many others. The ListView should resize regardless of what is inside the cells.

Comment: @Kenny Wyland: For any reasonable amount of rows for the user, a `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` will work. That's what the AOSP Contacts app does, for example -- even though Google uses `ListView` in a bunch of places you might not expect (e.g., a `PreferenceScreen`), when you need something like an `EditText` in "rows", they seem to lean towards the `ScrollView` approach. That doesn't work well for hundreds of "rows", but I would argue that the GUI design would be at fault there. Ideally, `ListView` would handle your scenario, but I won't be surprised if it doesn't.

Comment: I am dealing with tabular data which is arbitrarily long. A ListView is really the right thing to be using here for memory and processing efficiency. Saying, "Don't do that" isn't a helpful response and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Kenny Wyland: "A ListView is really the right thing to be using here for memory and processing efficiency." -- no, an `AdapterView` is really the right thing for memory and processing efficiency. A `ListView` may not be the right answer. For "tabular" contents, unless `GridView` happens to fit the bill, you're probably best suited rolling your own `AdapterView` implementation. Based on my Android experience (a wee bit more than yours), `ListView` with `EditTexts` in rows is an uncommon combination, and perhaps with reason.

Comment: So instead of using a ListView, you write your own ListView implementation? Doesn't that seem wrong to you?

Comment: @Kenny Wyland: "Doesn't that seem wrong to you?" -- not especially. Some day you will come to realize that not every class is optimal for every conceivable purpose. `ListView` is designed for lists of read-only widgets. The further you go from that design, the less likely it is to work properly. A tabular structure with `EditText` widgets is relatively far from what `ListView` was designed for. You might be able to hammer it into submission to meet your needs, but I certainly would not assume that it is necessarily possible or ideal.

Comment: First, "some day you will come to realize" sounds a little patronizing. I'm not a kid right out of college, I've been professionally developing software for 15+ years. The ListView is one of the most basic classes for showing a scrollable list of items and it works just fine with EditText fields in it. The problem had nothing to do with the ListView, it had to do with using WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN which interfered with automatic resizing for the keyboard.

Comment: I know that you have written many books including Android material, but reinventing the wheel every time sounds like a bad practice and if necessary then it sounds like the AndroidOS itself has some serious deficiencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're setting the Activity to Full Screen using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`, then the auto-resizing of the view doesn't work.  So unfortunately, your best bet is to not use Full Screen (i.e. have the status bar at the top visible), at which point the resizing will work normally.

Comment: That did it! I did have the activity set to full screen. Removing that line of code fixed it and the ListView is properly resizing.